# I get the sent at command and the response , both in the same response buffer

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, sim800, stm32f0

I am using SIM800 with STM32F0 in a project. I am using UART protocol for communication between them.
After sending the AT-COMMAND and I am waiting for response, I got both (AT-CMD + RESP)
Example:

```
sent: AT+FSLS=C:\ \r\n
resp: AT+FSLS=E:\ \r\n file.txt \r\n
```

In all application notes and in the response buffer, we just get the response like this:

```
sent: AT+FSLS=C:\ \r\n
resp: \r\n file.txt \r\n
```

Any hint?

Comment: It's hard to give any hint without seeing a single line of your code.

Comment: Have you checked echo setting of that AT channel? Try `ATE0` before you send other commands.

Comment: Hmmm. Is that a typo in the response or is it really `E:` instead of `C:` that was given in the command?

Comment: Thank you, when I send ATE0 it works very well !